# How do I parse a string in Python and obtain different datatypes out of it?

Tags: python

I have a string which is part of a list of the following form:-

```
[
'<Item Name1 (String with alphanumeric characters)> <Quantity1 (Int)> x <currency string> <Price1 (Float)>',
'<Item Name2 (String with alphanumeric characters)> <Quantity2 (Int)> x <currency string> <Price2 (Float)>',
'<Item Name3 (String with alphanumeric characters)> <Quantity3 (Int)> x <currency string> <Price3 (Float)>',
...]
```

How can parse this in the easiest form possible? Preferably something without regex, but I don't mind looking for a regex option if it is the simplest, since I just want the easiest way to do it.

EDIT:- Sample Input List

```
[
'Bananas Bunch 1 x EUR 3.99', 'Apples 5 x EUR 5.00', ....
]
```

Sample Output List

```
[
  {
    "name" : "Bananas Bunch", "quantity" : 1, "price": 3.99
  },
  {
    "name" : "Apples", "quantity" : 5, "price": 5.00
  }....
]
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and output?

Comment: I have added the input and output

Comment: A regular expression probably *is* the easiest way to do this, without getting into 3rd-party modules (which would be beyond the scope of Stack Overflow to address). The standard library doesn't contain any sort of parser-combinator module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression would be (I think) the most efficient way to do this. However, if you want to see a way to extract the info without regular expressions, the following would work. **IMPORTANT:** take into account that if a product's name includes the substring `' x '`, this solution would fail. I think it is not too common to have such a substring in a product's name, so it may work for almost all of them:

```
raw_products = ['Bananas Bunch 1 x EUR 3.99', 'Apples 5 x EUR 5.00']
parsed_products = []

for raw_product in raw_products:
    parsed_product = {}

    parts = raw_product.split(' x ')
    subparts = parts[0].split()

    parsed_product['name'] = ' '.join(subparts[:-1])
    parsed_product['quantity'] = int(subparts[-1])
    parsed_product['price'] = float(raw_product.split()[-1])

    parsed_products.append(parsed_product)

print(parsed_products)
```

Again, this might not be too efficient if we compare it with a regex solution. But if you do not mind efficiency and you want a shorter code, the following would be the same:

```
raw_products = ['Bananas Bunch 1 x EUR 3.99', 'Apples 5 x EUR 5.00']

parsed_products = [{
    'name': ' '.join(raw_product.split(' x ')[0].split()[:-1]),
    'quantity': int(raw_product.split(' x ')[0].split()[-1]),
    'price': float(raw_product.split()[-1])
} for raw_product in raw_products]

print(parsed_products)
```

Both solutions (well, they are really the same) would print the following:

```
[{'name': 'Bananas Bunch', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 3.99}, {'name': 'Apples', 'quantity': 5, 'price': 5.0}]
```

**EDIT**:
Well, I am not really into Regex (I still did not do many things with it), so the following may not be the shortest/cleanest way to do it, but the following code would work:

```
import re

raw_products = ['Bananas Bunch 1 x EUR 3.99', 'Apples 5 x EUR 5.00']
parsed_products = []

pattern = re.compile(r"""(?P<name>^.*(?=(\s[0-9]+\sx\s)))
                         \s(?P<quantity>[0-9]+(?=(\sx\s)))
                         .*\s(?P<price>[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$""", re.VERBOSE)

for raw_product in raw_products:
    match = pattern.match(raw_product)

    name = match.group('name')
    quantity = match.group('quantity')
    price = match.group('price')

    parsed_products.append({
        'name': name,
        'quantity': int(quantity),
        'price': float(price)
    })

print(parsed_products)
```

Or its shortest way (as in my previous answer):

```
import re

raw_products = ['Bananas Bunch 1 x EUR 3.99', 'Apples 5 x EUR 5.00']

pattern = re.compile(r"""(?P<name>^.*(?=(\s[0-9]+\sx\s)))
                         \s(?P<quantity>[0-9]+(?=(\sx\s)))
                         .*\s(?P<price>[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$""", re.VERBOSE)

parsed_products = [{
    'name': pattern.match(raw_product).group('name'),
    'quantity': int(pattern.match(raw_product).group('quantity')),
    'price': float(pattern.match(raw_product).group('price'))
} for raw_product in raw_products]

print(parsed_products)
```

I tried it also with a 'prone-to-fail' string like this one:

```
'An x box 360 1 x EUR 299.99'
```

And the output was also successful:

```
{'name': 'An x box 360', 'quantity': '1', 'price': '299.99'}
```

I am sorry if someone with strong knowledge of regex sees this and suffers a heart-attack! I just wanted to give a working solution, but my regex knowledge is actually limited.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the regex solution?

Comment: I edited my answer to give a potential solution with regex :)

Answer (score 0):

```
inp = ['Bananas Bunch 1 x EUR 3.99', 'Apples 5 x EUR 5.00']
str_nums = []
currency = ['EUR', 'USD']
output = []
for i in range(100):
    str_nums.append(str(i))

for i in inp:
    name = ''
    t = i.split()
    for j in t:
        if j in str_nums:
            break
        else:
            name += (j + " ")
    name = name.rstrip()
    # print(t, name)
    output.append({'name': name})
print(output)
```

This is a crude working for name alone. I assume you will have some kind of pattern in your input. Make use of that to split the input and bifurcate them
into the respective categories.
For the currency part, make a list of all types of currency accepted, and the following string, i.e. the string after splitting, should be your currency value (keep in mind it will be string and not float and you will have to convert).